# Rails 5 - set value on self based on matching fields with a Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In the app that I am building to learn Ruby and Rails, I have trouble getting below to work.

### Desired result

when the content of the field `self.extracted_data` (here self is object `Document`) contains the bank account number (`bank_account`) of a business partner (`BusinessPartner`), the sender for the document (`self.sender_id`) needs to equal the BusinessPartner.

What I have so far:

```
BusinessPartner.active.each do |business_partner|
   unless business_partner == self.receiver_id
      if self.extracted_data =~ /\s#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account)}?\s/i # need to fix the RGX
        self.sender = business_partner
        self.name = "match: " + business_partner.id.to_s + /\s#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account)}?\s/i.to_s # to see RGX used
      else
        self.sender = nil
        self.name = "NO match: " + business_partner.id.to_s + /\s#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account)}?\s/i.to_s # to see RGX used
      end
  end
end
```

It always gives me NO MATCH where I do have 100% matching records for business partners. I have been studying the pickaxe book, rails doc etc. for hours now and can find the solution. **All help / advice welcome.**

p.s. I could DRY the regex into a variable yet it is used multiple times only temporarily.

### update

sample data for **business partners**
[image]

sample data for **extracted_data**

could include the bank-account...

- enclosed in whitespace eg: ' NL15 INGB 0660 3125 06 '
- enclosed in whitespace and a dot (.) eg: ' GB99 RBS1 0469 7788 99.'
- enclosed in brackets () eg: (NL15 INGB 0660 3125 06)
- although not allowed by the banks, could have special characters; typically dot (.) or dash (-)
- or like so: ' 19.83.94.527 ' (very uncommon; no need to cater.

Note: bank account should adhere to IBAN formatting rules. These will be applied to the business_partner.bank_account field for data quality; yet what is in the extracted_data depends on what it extracted from the file (pdf) attached to the document record.

Comment: Is the value always enclosed with whitespace? Try removing `\s` from your pattern. Or replace with `\b` (word boundaries). Or replace the first `\s` with `(?<!\S)` and the last one with `(?!\S)`. If you provide sample data, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: added more info / sample data

Comment: I hope it is not the actual data :)? It seems that you need to replace `\s` with `\b`. `if self.extracted_data =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account)}?\b/i`

Comment: all publicly avail online. tried that one too. May be the ruby code; it always comes with No match on the bank account of 1 specific business partner.

Comment: Which one? Try `if self.extracted_data =~ /(?<!\w)#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account)}?(?!\w)/i`

Comment: the one with bank account 19.83.94.527. When I add that to extracted_data it matches and assigns the sender.

Comment: It works as long as the bank account does not contain any whitespace. e.g. this matches "NL23ABNA0469823526", where this "NL23 ABNA 0469 8235 26" does not. problem, the last notation/format is normally found in the documents as that is the printed version of IBAN.

Comment: You might remove spaces before the regex extraction - `if self.extracted_data.gsub(/\s+/, '') =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account)}?\b/i`

Comment: Don't forget to post as answer :)

Comment: Great, I just was not sure it worked well for you. Posted with a bit of an explanation.

Comment: sued the sub also on the bank_account field now ;-) (with regex.escape it strips dash or dot). Now need to fix the iteration (see other question if you got time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace the `\s` whitespace patterns with word boundaries `\b` to avoid requiring whitespace around the pattern (word boundaries are zero-width assertions, and they only match *locations* in a string, so they are safe to use in the extraction scenario, similarly to lookarounds), and since there are whitespace symbols in the original string, you may just remove them with `.gsub(/\s+/, '')` for the sake of regex checking:

```
if self.extracted_data.gsub(/\s+/, '') =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account)}?\b/i
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^                                               ^^^
```

See more  about word boundaries on the [*Word Boundaries* regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) Web page.